# Composition measurability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Suppose that $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  and $N:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are random variables in the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.Show that $\omega\mapsto X_{N{\omega}}(\omega) $ is also a random variable in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.

Because $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a random variable we know that

$\forall E\in Y(\text{image space of}  X_{n})$

$X^{-1}_{n}(E)=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\forall n,X_{n}(\omega)\in E \right\}\in \mathcal{F}$

and for N

$\forall A\in \mathbb{N}$

$N^{-1}(A)=\left\{\omega\in \Omega:N(\omega)\in A\right\}\in \mathcal{F}$

Now we are going to prove that

$\forall P\in Y$

$X^{-1}_{N}(P)=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\forall N(\omega)\in \mathbb{N},X_{N(\omega)}(\omega)\in P\right\}\in \mathcal{F}$

We can rewrite $\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\forall N(\omega)\in \mathbb{N},X_{N(\omega)}(\omega)\in P\right\}=\bigcap_{N(\omega)\in \mathbb{N}}\left\{\omega\in \Omega:X_{N(\omega)}(\omega)\in P\right\}$

Next we choose $\omega \in X^{-1}_{n}(E)$ and for that $\omega$ we take the correspondent $N(\omega)$ which takes value in $\mathbb{N}$.But $X^{-1}_{n}(E)$ is measurable for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ . So for $N(\omega)=n$
   ,$X^{-1}_{N(\omega)}(E)\in \mathcal{F}$

So the $\bigcap_{N(\omega)\in \mathbb{N}}X^{-1}_{N(\omega)}(E)$ is measurable.

Is this proof correct ?? (Is it  like taking a subsequence of $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ and showing that is measurable ??)

Comment: No, it's not. It starts to go wrong where you claim that $$X_N^{-1}(P) = \{\omega \in \Omega; \forall N(\omega) \in \mathbb{N}, X_{N(\omega)}(\omega) \in P\}.$$ This does not hold true (...actually I can't make any sense of the right-hand side); it should read $$X_N^{-1}(P) = \{\omega \in \Omega; X_{N(\omega)}(\omega) \in P\}.$$ (Let me also remark that $E$ (or $P$) is not just any subset of the image space, but actually an element of the sigma-field on the image space.)